# List Comprehension doesn't work as expected

Tags: python, list-comprehension

In trying to use list comprehension more often I tried to code golf an assignment.  So this works:

```
if fraction[0] % i == 0 and fraction[1] % i == 0:
            fraction = [fraction[x]/i for x in range(2)]
```

But this doesn't work:

```
fraction = [fraction[x]/i for x in range(2) if fraction[0] % i == 0 and fraction[1] % i == 0]
```

It gives a `list index out of range` error

Fraction is a two item list and the if statement has a specific indices which should never be out of range... thoughts?

Comment: Haven't tested, but it very well could be the use of `fraction` as the assignment name and inside the comprehension. I believe the LHS name is reserved before the comprehension is evaluated, so the `fraction` inside the comprehension is referencing your still-empty list.

Comment: If I test this with `fraction = [3,9]`, it works in `python3`. Please provide a testcase that reproduces the error.

Comment: Could you give a value for `fraction` and `i` where the first works and the second doesn't?  Also, FWIW, these are different statements.  The first will only change `fraction` if the conditional returns `True`.  The second will change `fraction` to an empty list if the conditional returns `False` (which may lead to `IndexError` later if this is in a loop).

Comment: @mgilson Totally right.  It's absolutely a loop and fraction ends up being an empty list after the very first time it comes back false.  I just assumed that it would leave fraction alone if it was false.  Gonna write this down in my lessons learned about python doc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that in the second case, `fraction` always gets overridden.

So for example, if `fraction = [2, 4]` and `i = 3`, your list comprehension will result in `fraction == []`, while the loop will just do nothing.

**UPDATE**

Here's the code I tested with:

```
def a(fraction, i):
    if fraction[0] % i == 0 and fraction[1] % i == 0:
        fraction = [fraction[x] // i for x in range(2)]
    return fraction

def b(fraction, i):
    fraction = [fraction[x] // i for x in range(2) if fraction[0] % i == 0 and fraction[1] % i == 0]
    return fraction

print(a([2, 4], 3)) # Output: [2, 4]
print(b([2, 4], 3)) # Ouptut: []
```

**GOLF UPDATE**

I think if you can reverse the order you're testing values in, your list comprehension can work. E.g.:

```
f = next([n//i for n in f] for i in range(max(f),0,-1) if all(n%i==0 for n in f))
```

Test:

```
for fraction in ('2/4', '1/5', '4/2', '1/9'):
    f = [int(x) for x in fraction.split('/')]
    f = next([n//i for n in f] for i in range(max(f),0,-1) if all(n%i==0 for n in f))
    print('/'.join(map(str,f)))

# Output:
# 1/2
# 1/5
# 2/1
# 1/9
```

Comment: Thanks and dang thats alota nested for loops and if statements.  Well played sir.  A question though:
What is the next() doing?  Don't the for loops automatically move through the various lists.

Comment: `next` just returns the first thing in the iterator.